# Importing from CSV and changing projection using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system, shapefile, csv, error-000732

I'm attempting to convert CSV files to a group of shapefiles, then re-project them to a different coordinate system.

The first conversion works, but I'm having issues with the projection piece.

```
import arcpy
import os
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join, basename

csvpath = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
outshapefolder = r'U:\skelley\Python\FWD_GPR_import\SampleCSVout2'

files = [join(csvpath,f) for f in listdir(csvpath) if isfile(join(csvpath, f))]

for f in files:
    arcpy.MakeTableView_management(in_table=f, out_view='tempview')
    arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management(table='tempview', in_x_field='Lat', in_y_field='Lon',
                                 out_layer='tempevent', spatial_reference=4326)
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(in_features='tempevent', 
   out_feature_class=join(outshapefolder,basename(f).replace('.csv','.shp')))

#set new projection
outCS = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
SR = arcpy.SpatialReference()  #an empty spatial reference object
SR.loadFromString(outCS)

inshape = r'U:\skelley\Python\FWD_GPR_import\SampleCSVout2'
outshape = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

#loop through new shapefiles to project
for x in listdir(inshape):
    if x.endswith('.shp'):

        #Determine the new output feature class path and name
        infc = os.path.join(inshape, x)
        outfc = os.path.join(outshape, x)

        #Run project tool
        arcpy.Project_management(infc, outfc, outCS, 'NAD_1983_HARN_To_WGS_1984_2')
```

Comment: In your filestoo = [join(inshape,x) for x in listdir(inshape) if isfile(join(inshape, x))] you need to only keep the shapefiles, not all the other files. Try arcpy.ListFeatureClasses https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//03q300000023000000 (set your arcpy.env.workspace = inshape) instead of os.listdir to get only the shape files. The error message is telling you that your file (.cpg) isn't something that it understands as a feature class to be projected not that the file doesn't exist, the error  message is a little ambiguous.

Comment: Or, if you prefer: `glob.glob(os.path.join(inshape, "*.shp"))`

Comment: @MichaelStimson - so when you say "only keep the shapefiles" - does that mean literally only something ending in .shp in the file location? I don't really know how this works, but I've noticed that shapefiles appear as one object in the Arcmap catalog, and several in the actual file location.

Comment: Yes, there are at least 3 files that make a shapefile: .shp, .shx and .dbf see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile for more info. If you iterate with listfiles you need to filter out everything but the .shp (you can use os.path.splitext which returns a tuple of file name and extension), arcpy.ListFeatureClasses returns *only* the shape files, like you see in Catalog.

Comment: Which line of code produces the error?

Comment: @MichaelStimson I attempted ListFeatureClasses, and the code didn't throw any errors, but didn't re-project the shapefiles. What are your thoughts?

Comment: @EmilBrundage I've made some alterations since then, but I believe it was the Project_management function.

Comment: Can you update your code to what it has been changed to, provided the answer given does not work for you; If you have implemented the answer successfully then please accept it to show that it meets your needs.

Comment: @MichaelStimson have updated the code for your perusal.

Answer (score 3):

I guess Michael Stimson is suggesting to do something like:

```
for x in filestoo:

        if x.endswith('shp'):
            # Determine the new output feature class path and name
            outfc = os.path.join(outshape, x)

            # run project tool
            arcpy.Project_management(x, outfc, outCS)
```

Comment: Sort of, it's more like arcpy.env.workspace = r'U:\skelley\Python\FWD_GPR_import\SampleCSVout2' then filestoo = [os.path.join(inshape,x) for x in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses('\*.SHP')] which will give you *only the feature classes* in the workspace; as the workspace is a folder then feature classes are most likely to be shapefiles but can also be CAD files and other, rarer, formats. Specifying the wildcard '\*.shp' (not case sensitive) will return a list of *only the shapefiles* in that folder.

Comment: @MichaelStimson I've edited the code above to reflect the current state. It now seems to work until arcpy.Project_management(), then it kicks out this: "ERROR 000670: output Output Dataset or Feature Class is same as input Input Dataset or Feature Class." Does this mean it doesn't like the fact that the output file names are the same as input? I thought it wouldn't matter, since I'm putting them in a different file location.

Comment: That should only happen if parameter 3 (output workspace) is U:\skelley\Python\FWD_GPR_import\SampleCSVout2, you can reuse the same name but not in the same folder, the input is locked and can't be overwritten, but you can project to os.environ.get('TEMP') and then use arcpy.Copy_management to do the overwriting - a simple two-step change but I would caution against that, it's usually best to keep your original files (or a backup of such) just in case the process does something you didn't anticipate and destroys your data.

Comment: @MichaelStimson My output workspace isn't U:\skelley\Python\FWD_GPR_import\SampleCSVout2; that's the weird part. Any theories?

Comment: Take the join out of filestoo = [join(inshape,x) for x in listdir(inshape) if x.endswith('.shp')].. at this point only the *names* of the feature classes are required then in arcpy.Project_management(x, outfc, outCS, 'NAD_1983_HARN_To_WGS_1984_2') make the first parameter join(inshape,x) and that should  (might) fix the problem.

Comment: @MichaelStimson Doing exactly that didn't work, but I tried my own variant (see edits above). Now I'm getting a different error: ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
invalid extent for output coordinate system
Failed to execute (Project). My datasets are within the extent of the projection, so I'm not sure what's going on here. My map is also set to the new projection.

Comment: I think that is worthy of a new question, I am not an expert in North American datums and their conversion.

Comment: @MichaelStimson I appreciate you trying to help. I tried to convert these files manually with the geoprocessing tools and it didn't work - I'm thinking there's an issue with the shapefiles the first part of my code created. I'm going to regroup and try another question, as you suggest. Again, thanks!